# Thousands grouping in python on MacOS

Tags: python, locale

The following 4 lines of code work as expected on Windows and Linux, but don't seem to work on MacOS (Python 3.8.9):

```
>>> import locale
>>> language_code, encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, (language_code, encoding))
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> locale.format_string("%.8f", 100000000.1, grouping=True)
'100,000,000.09999999'
```

On MacOS, the `grouping=True` parameter seems to be ignored, even when the default locale is well defined. The string is formatted like this: `100000000.09999999`

I tried it on various machines, and the problem was confirmed by all of my MacOS users.

Is there a way to print a number with thousands separator on MacOS?

Comment: Maybe related? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69940/office-for-mac-excel-app-doesnt-show-thousand-separator

Comment: Cannot reproduce on macOS 10.15.7 using the system-installed Python 3.8.2.

Comment: In the meantime, I was able to find a MacOS computer on which it works. I'm still trying to figure out on which versions of MAcOS and/or python it fails. Unfortunately my users are technically versed enough to work with terminals.

Comment: Different versions of operating system have different versions of the locale data, currently some locales have grouping separators and some don't